# MySQL Query (Group by)

Tags: mysql, sql

2 I have two tables

one logs.emails:

```
EmailNum  EmployeeID,   Emailcontent,  EmailReceivers    ,is_read
  1          1       ,   "sasa"     ,   "sas@google.com" ,1
  2          1       ,   "sasa"     ,   "sas@google.com" ,0
  3          2       ,   "sasa"     ,   "sas@google.com" ,0
  4          2       ,   "sasa"     ,   "sas@google.com" ,0
  5          2       ,   "sasa"     ,   "sas@google.com" ,0
```

and Employees.user

```
id, FirstName, LastNAme
1 , "John"   , "Brown"
2 , "Jack"   , "James"
```

My desired Output:

> FirstName, LastName, NumOfUnreadEmails
>   John     , Brown   , 1
>   Jack   , James     ,3

My attempt(But it does not return the irst row of desired output which is "John     , Brown    ,1"):

```
SELECT 
    *, count(EmployeeID) as NumEmails 
FROM 
    logs.emails a
inner join 
    Employees.user b on a.EmployeeID=b.id 
group by 
    EmployeeID 
having 
    a.is_read='0'
```

Your help is appreciated

Comment: Should Jack James have id of 2 above? They both have same id presently.

Comment: You can't do `*, COUNT(` since you would have to group all columns.  Are you just wanting * from `Employees.user`?

Comment: YEs kind of; also I need the number of unread emails!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify a `WHERE` clause here instead of using `HAVING`, as you are trying to filter out the records that have `is_read=0` prior to doing any aggregation.

Also, in order to get only the fields desired, don't use `*` . Simply specify the fields you want.

```
SELECT 
    b.FirstName, b.LastName, COUNT(a.EmailNum)
FROM 
    logs.emails a
inner join 
    Employees.user b on a.EmployeeID=b.id 
where 
    a.is_read='0'
group by 
    b.id
```

Comment: This doesn't return employees that have no unread e-mails or no e-mails at all. Maybe that's okay, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: I dont want to return either!

Comment: That was not mentioned as a requirement, but if needed, you could refer to the answer that you had provided which provides this result.

Comment: I'm not saying either is better. Just pointing out the differences. :)

Comment: @Mike: no my query is wrong count(EmployeeID) needs to be replaced with COUNT(a.EmailNum)

Comment: This doesn't mention the actual problem with the OP query. The problem is that a `HAVING` clause on a non-aggregate expression in a GROUP BY query is indeterminate for expressions not included in the GROUP BY. (The answer doesn't point out that the HAVING clause was removed, and replaced by a WHERE clause.) Replacing `*` with a list of expressions is best practice, but it has nothing to do with fixing the actual problem. (The comment from GolezTrol will be helpful for future readers, who are looking for an answer to a similar question, but who do need to include zero counts.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
SELECT b.FirstName, b.LastName, 
       sum( case
              when a.is_read=0 than 1
              else 0
             end ) as NumOfUnreadEmails
FROM logs.emails a 
inner join Employees.user b on a.EmployeeID=b.id 
group by b.FirstName, b.LastName
```

Comment: This will not return a count of zero for any employees.user that doesn't have any email. There are ways to write the statement that will return a zero count, as well as (potentially) improve performance by including a predicate on `logs.emails.is_read = 0`

Answer (score 1):

This will return all employees, including the ones that don't have any e-mail at all. If you want to show only the ones that do have unread e-mail, you can change `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
  u.FirstName,
  u.LastName,
  COUNT(e.EmployeeID) AS NumOfUnreadEmails
FROM
  Employees.user u
  LEFT JOIN logs.emails e ON e.EmployeeID = u.id AND e.is_read = 0
GROUP BY
  u.id
```

Comment: This is SO close! But aggregate really needs to be something like `COUNT(e.EmployeeID)`, so that we get a zero count for the users with zero unread emails.

Comment: +1. Yes, that's the ticket. We might note that a "covering index" e.g. `ON logs.emails (EmployeeID, is_read)` may significantly improve performance of the query. (And now just simply removing the `LEFT` keyword would eliminate the rows with a zero count.)

Comment: We might also mention that other DBMS would require "`GROUP BY u.FirstName, u.LastName`" (i.e. all non-aggregates in the SELECT list). But the query above is valid with MySQL, but that's a because of a MySQL specific extension which is not SQL-92 compliant.